# Crash with subsetting TemporalData

Tags: bugs, crash, time-series

The first line gets a single sample path for an M/M/1 queue for time between 0 and 100. No problem, I can plot it, etc.

```
td = RandomFunction[QueueingProcess[9, 10], {0, 100}, 1];
```

Next, I want to look at the sample path of the process between time 10 and 50, so I do

```
subset = td["Part", 1, {10, 50}];
```

and MMA crashes on me. Ver 9.0.1.0 on windows 7 64 bit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `td["Part", 1, {10, 50, 1}]`

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, it does stop it from crashing, but then I only get the subset at the 1 time unit resolution. I really want it at at all points of change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in part extraction for `TemporalData`.  You can work around it by giving your times explicitly.

`subset = td["Part", 1, {Cases[td["PathTimes"], x_ /; 10 <= x <= 50]}]`

I have a feeling this is more in the spirit of what you want here anyway.

The "Part" property resamples the data so that it is uniformly spaced if you give `{tmin, tmax, dt}`.  You omit the `dt` so it has to be inferred. In your case it should be trying to use the smallest time step in your data.  This will result in a very large data object in this case because the smallest step is incredibly small compared to the time range you want.

**EDIT**

It is additionally worth mentioning that "Part" uses the "PathFunctions" to build the subset. When you just want a window it can be unnecessarily expensive for continuous time process data. It is trivial to get what you want from the data itself and avoid building "PathFunctions".

`Cases[td["Path", 1], {t_/; 10<=t<=50, _}]`